# error in node js when trying to install a module in windows

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to install a module called synchronize in node js .

I got this error. I am in windows  :

> fibers@1.0.6 install                               C:\Users\Kobbi\WebstormProjects\untitled19\node_modules\synchronize
>     \node_modules\fibers
>   node build.js || nodejs build.js
>
> win32-ia32-v8-3.28` exists; testing Problem with the binary; manual
>   build incoming
>
> C:\Users\Kobbi\WebstormProjects\untitled19\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers>if
>   not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin
>   \node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild
>   --release )  else (nod e  rebuild --release ) Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add  the
>   "/m" switch.
>   C:\Users\Kobbi\WebstormProjects\untitled19\node_modules\synchronize\node_modules\fibers\b
>   uild\fibers.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported project
>   "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default. props" was not found. Confirm that the path
>   in the  declaration is correct, and t hat the file exists on
>   disk. gyp ERR! build error gyp ERR! stack Error:
>   `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed w
>   ith exit code: 1 gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\
>   node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:269:23) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17) gyp ERR! stack     at
>   Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1074:12) gyp
>   ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601 gyp ERR! command "node" "C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\
>   \node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release" gyp ERR! cwd
>   C:\Users\Kobbi\WebstormProjects\untitled19\node_modules\synchronize\node_modu
>   les\fibers gyp ERR! node -v v0.12.7 gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v2.0.1 gyp
>   ERR! not ok Build failed 'nodejs' is not recognized as an internal or
>   external command, operable program or batch file. npm ERR! Windows_NT
>   6.1.7601 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\node js\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js"
>   "install" "synchronize" npm ERR! node v0.12.7 npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>
> npm ERR! fibers@1.0.6 install: `node build.js || nodejs build.js` npm
>   ERR! Exit status 1 npm ERR! npm ERR! Failed at the fibers@1.0.6
>   install script 'node build.js || nodejs build.js'. npm ERR! This is
>   most likely a problem with the fibers package, npm ERR! not with npm
>   itself. npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system: npm
>   ERR!     node build.js || nodejs build.js npm ERR! You can get their
>   info via: npm ERR!     npm owner ls fibers npm ERR! There is likely
>   additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\Kobbi\WebstormProjects\untitled19\npm-debug.log

I would appreciate any help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well -- the good news is that you shouldn't see that error, that bad news is that it appears the latest Fibers (1.0.6) has a corrupted binary file in the npm implementation for Windows (at least Windows 7 x32 bit).  I presume you are on node 0.10.xx?

Here is a link to a github issue on this subject: 
https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers/issues/236

Alas, I don't know of a good work around because it appears that Fibers@1.0.5 binary is no longer available on npm!  So it tries to build that too.

Alas, the github README.md is pretty vague about how to actually compile this on Windows. Here is the blurb (below). Since I don't have a full development environment I can't even try it out .. but again, we shouldn't have to. :(

from source

```
git clone git://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers.git
cd node-fibers
npm install
```

> Note: node-fibers uses node-gyp for building. To manually invoke the
>   build process, you can use node-gyp rebuild. This will put the
>   compiled extension in build/Release/fibers.node. However, when you do
>   require('fibers'), it will expect the module to be in, for example,
>   bin/linux-x64-v8-3.11/fibers.node. You can manually put the module
>   here every time you build, or you can use the included build script.
>   Either npm install or node build -f will do this for you. If you are
>   going to be hacking on node-fibers, it may be worthwhile to first do
>   node-gyp configure and then for subsequent rebuilds you can just do
>   node-gyp build which will be faster than a full npm install or
>   node-gyp rebuild.

Comment: Actually -- the Fibers@1.0.5 for Windows works fine (well, presumably except for whatever they change for 1.0.6 :) -- so as a work around perhaps you could just modify the package.json file and change the fiber version from 1.0.6 to 1.0.5.

Comment: Hi, @sjmcdowall. I have the similar problem with NPM on my Windows machine. I created the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34335043/troubles-with-npm-and-node-gyp-in-windows Maybe you have some useful advices for me?